# MbedTLS with Bluetooh Low Energy

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, mbedtls

Does somebody has experience with implementing the MbedTLS with the BLE devices. I have few questions about setting up the read and write call back functions for the mbedtls_set_bio() functions. I wanted to use the GATT api functions to set up the tunnel with MbedTLS. I am completely new to the mbedTLS and the BLE. I am not quite sure about how to set up these call backs and what exactly they should do. I am using the dialogs DA14695 USB sticks to implement the DTLS handshake between the two BLE devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://forums.mbed.com/t/modifying-the-tls-library-to-encrypt-over-ble/3472/5

Comment: Yeah, I have seen this post and understood we can make use of GAAT services and characteristics and I am not sure how exactly to link both the mbedtls and the BLE.